# why do some processes fail to finish their whole run sometimes?

Tags: c++, process

I'm running the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void foo() {
    fork();
    fork();
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    fork();
}

int main() {
    foo();
    cout << "main" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and I cant seem to get a defined output. I understand not to expect one single output since each process may run differently, however even though I expect 4 hello worlds, and 8 main's, maybe in a different order, sometimes I can get 2 hello worlds and 6 main's.

Comment: Perhaps some of the forks fail. Why don't you also dump what each fork returns.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: The same way the shown code prints the two messages?

Comment: [`fork()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) returns PID of new process or `-1` if error occurred. You can check `errno` for more details about the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void foo() {
    cout << getpid() << " => " << fork() << " from " << getpid() << endl;
    cout << getpid() << " => " << fork() << " from " << getpid() << endl;
    cout << getpid() << " Hello World!" << endl;
    cout << getpid() << " => " << fork() << " from " << getpid() << endl;
}

int main() {
    cout << "PID: " << getpid() << endl;
    foo();
    cout << getpid() << " main" << endl;
}
```

Possible output:

```
PID: 12385
12385 => 12386 from 12385
12385 => 12387 from 12385
12385 Hello World!
12385 => 0 from 12386
12385 => 0 from 12387
12387 Hello World!
12385 => 12388 from 12385
12385 main
12386 => 12389 from 12386
12386 Hello World!
12385 => 0 from 12388
12388 main
12387 => 12390 from 12387
12387 main
12386 => 0 from 12389
12389 Hello World!
12386 => 12391 from 12386
12386 main
12387 => 0 from 12390
12390 main
12386 => 0 from 12391
12389 => 12392 from 12389
12391 main
12389 main
12389 => 0 from 12392
12392 main
```

On my system everything works as you expect. Probably some `fork` calls do not work for you and return `-1`.

The output is to be interpreted as follows.

```
12385 => 12386 from 12385
12385 => 0 from 12386
```

The first line is from the original process, the second from the forked process. Both come from the first `cout` line.

In the case of a failure, there would be only one line.

```
12385 => -1 from 12385
```